# Robot Framework: 'Get Regexp Matches' returns empty list

Tags: python, robotframework, string-matching

I have a list of string items where I'm trying to extract a set of digits from each string.

I iterate over the list (known number of items) and split each string since they contain multiple sets of digits, but I know where the set I'm interested in is located.

Then, I use the 'Get Regexp Matches' to try and extract the digits using the regular expression below. The digits can be negative and of varying number of digits.

```
FOR    {i}    IN    ${iterations}
    ${offset_string}=    Split String    ${deviation_list[${i}]}    separator=:
    ${offset}=    Get Regexp Matches    ${offset_string[1]}    -?\d+
.
.
.
END
```

When running this, the ${offset} output from 'Get Regexp Matches' is an empty list, indicating there were no matches. However, I'm 100% positive there are digits in each string item which should be found.

I have checked my regular expression using regexe101.com along with an example of my strings, and it says it should be fine.

I have also tried using 'Get Regexp Matches' with a simple string as regular expression, and that works. Doing this, it successfully finds matches in my strings.

I also tried including whitespaces before my digits, \s-?\d+, but I still only get an empty list.

Here's an example of a string item from my list: "phc_ctl[45.908]: offset from CLOCK_REALTIME is 2237ns"

I expect the output to be ${offset} = ['2237'] with this example using my code.

Answer (score 2):

With Robot Framework you need to escape each `\` with another. So the correct regular expression for you would be `-?\\d+`.

You can also check the regexp stuff in more detail in the [Robot Framework User Guide](https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#using-custom-regular-expressions).